# AJAX + PHP function inside class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using MVC pattern in my project and I have controller product with method delete($slug)

On my page (~/show/basket) I have products that user wants to buy. There's a 'delete' button and when he clicks on that button I want to delete that product from SESSION and remove from current page.

I was trying with jquery ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.on-delete').on('click', function() {
    var path = '/ITAKADEMIJA_zavrsni_rad/3-itcomm/';
    var slug = $(this).data('slug');

    $.ajax({
        url: $(location).attr('host') + path + 'product/delete/' + slug,
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('ERROR!');
        }
    });
 });
});
```

and then I have a method delete inside product controller

```
public function delete($slug)
{

    $cardModel = $this->model('Card');

    if ($slug === null) {
        header("Location:" . BASE_ROOT . '/show/products');
    } else if ($cardModel->getProduct($slug)) {
        $product = $cardModel->getProduct($slug);
        $cardModel->removeProduct($product);
        header("Location: " . BASE_ROOT . '/show/basket');
    }
}

public function removeProduct($product)
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['products'][$product->slug])) 
    {
        unset($_SESSION['products'][$product->slug]);
    } 
}
```

Now the problem is:

1. I'm getting this error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'App\Controllers\Show' does not have a method 'index' in C:\Users\nikol\Dropbox\www\ITAKADEMIJA_zavrsni_rad\3-itcomm\app\Core\App.php on line 50

2. Nothing happens, that product is still in session. It looks like that function wasn't even called.

I would like to call the function, that function should remove product from session and from that page.

Comment: What is inside delete method? Error is there

Comment: Why are you posting an error message but not the code it references?

Comment: What's in C:\Users\nikol\Dropbox\www\ITAKADEMIJA_zavrsni_rad\3-itcomm\app\Core\App.php on line 50?

Comment: Line 50: `call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);`
It calls method inside that class ~/product/delete/{$slug} 
product - class, delete - method, argument - slug
It works fine when I'm not using ajax. When I use
`<a href="~/product/delete/$slug>Delete</a>"`, but I want to use AJAX instead.